# Scalable approaches to map URLs to file-names

Tags: ruby

Problem: There are millions URLs (in the format: http://example.com/some_page) and I need to convert these URL names into something that I can later use for a file name (many OSes don't allow you to have a colon or a dash in the file name).

So far I've tried this in a hope I wouldn't use a key-value database because of base64 simple encoding/decoding:

```
require 'base64'

p Base64.encode64('insert some REALLY long URL here') # would produce some random name to use as a filename

# I'd do Base64.decode64 to later to get back to the URL
```

The problem with it is that the longer the URL is, the longer the base64 string will be. Which is bad, because OSes have limits of how long a file name can be.

I've also tried secure_random, however, the problem is, a) randomness isn't guaranteed b) I'd have to use some database in order to map the random strings to the URLs.

It would be ideal if there was some scheme which allows you to enter a string and convert it to alpha-numeric characters of FIXED length which could be used as a file name and then easily de-coded into the original string. If such a thing doesn't exist, then what would be the next-best approach for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL already is a file path and filename, only it also has a protocol prepended to it. So, use tools designed to work with URLs and split them into the parts you need:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://example.com/some_page')
uri.path # => "/some_page"
```

From `/some_page` it's hard to tell exactly what is being looked at. It could be two directories, or a directory and a file, so it takes some advance knowledge of a site to say for sure, but, either way, there are tools that make it easier to work with:

```
uri_path = uri.path
File.dirname(uri_path) # => "/"
File.basename(uri_path) # => "some_page"
File.split(uri_path) # => ["/", "some_page"]
```

The given example isn't revealing too much about how `dirname`, `basename` and `split` work, but you can read more about them in the `File` documentation. And, what you want to do with those components is up to you.

It's possible to extract the host info too:

```
uri.host # => "example.com"
```

Because `.` is valid in a filename or path, it's OK to keep the name as is. However, it's important to understand that hostnames aren't necessarily in ASCII. The internet is constantly changing, and [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) standards allow for binary characters that your OS might not like, or that your brain and eyes, or those of your customers, might not like. So, that presents a problem of how to correctly build paths on disk pointing to files.

While encoding the name using Base64 could possibly work, you'd still have the potential of lookups taking forever just to return a list of files and where they came from. Searches would be painful, horribly so.

Instead, I'd strongly recommend building a database that is used to map URLs to file paths. A database can even be used to contain the files, or you could simply rename the files to the row_ID of the related record. The database can also contain meta-data about the files, such as file-types, sizes, date/time stamps when the file was first retrieved, if/when it was updated, last time it was checked, etc. The database becomes the central point of knowledge about the files, and files on disk are merely one part of that information.

You have to decide how you're going to implement this, as there are any number of ways to map a resource to a file but trying to create a huge hierarchy of site/path/to/resource files on disk based on splitting up the URL isn't going to scale well or play nice with your disk.

---

> What type of database would be most suitable for storing HTML content? With million of HTML pages, that db would be huge...

A decent one? I can't say because I have no idea what you're doing, but MySQL or PostgreSQL could easily handle this if you're saving the pages. If not, then a key/value store would work if you only need metadata. A million rows isn't that much these days. A better question is, how much disk space, RAM, how many CPUs and what network bandwidth will you need?

To process millions of pages a day will take a couple hosts running constantly against the database and retrieving pages, if you're doing analysis or scraping and updating pages, and will involve moving a lot of text. (I've been known to have the highest network utilization in our company when I was in charge of writing site analytic and scraping code of some fortune 500 companies and have written hundreds of spiders, so I have some idea of the issues encountered.)

Why store millions of pages?

- Are you also going to store all the other related resources/objects that go with the page? Do you want to be able to regurgitate those pages to others? Are you going to rewrite all the embedded links to those resources?
- Do you want to only check for changes to a page? If so, there are better ways of tracking that than storing the whole page.
- Do you want to act as a search engine for those pages? Then store the metadata you want to provide and toss the HTML after processing it.

Many HTTPd servers support ETag and various other headers that let you tell whether it knowns if a page changed since it was last seen. A HEAD request can help too. At the worst, it should be sufficient using MD5 to to see if a cached page and a recently retrieved remote page match by comparing a stored MD5 value and computing it for the fresh one.

Comment: With millions of URLs there will be some with the same path. I need to convert the entire URL, starting from http and ending at the uri path, so I can later refer to it exactly.

Comment: Patience grasshopper. It takes time to create decent answers.

Comment: So I'm guessing that something like using securerandom (which has low probability of a duplicate) with duplicate checking and a simple key-value db like GDBM to map the values will do the job. What type of database would be most suitable for storing HTML content? With million of HTML pages, that db would be huge...

Comment: see the additional info

Comment: I'll need to store their HTML and then do various queries on them FAST, so storing their HTML locally is a must. So it's closest to being a search engine for those pages, but I'm not sure how tossing the HTML would help, if I want to do a query on all pages, for example, and see if a text area HTML element is contained in them, the metadata alone won't help. Neither some advanced queries for Google since this is a custom list and all pages can be coming from different URLs.